# cross domain problem in geodjango for openlayers in django development server

Tags: openlayers-2, geodjango, cors

I want to display geojson data on map in geodjango. Below is my code
template/map.html (javascript code). only the map is loading but not the geojson data. Whwn I used debugger the url is gettin geojson data but not displaying on map and I'm not getting any errors.

```
<script>

        var map,layer;
        var zoom=8;
        var lon=45;
        var lat=5;
        function init(){
             map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
             layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", 
                    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                    {layers: 'basic'} );
                      map.addLayer(layer);
                      map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);


            var featurecollection = {{geojson}};
            <!-- var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(); -->
            var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            });
            var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(); 

            vector_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.parseFeature(featurecollection));
            vector_layer.addFeatures(featurecollection);


            map.addLayer(vector_layer);

        }
```

views.py

```
def geojson_provinces(request):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="geodjango",host='localhost',user='postgres', password='postgres', port=5433)
    dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    res = dict_cur.execute("SELECT ST_AsGeoJson(geom) AS json FROM pft_pft LIMIT 10;")

    points=dict_cur.fetchall()
    print (points)
    json_res  = []
    for row in points:
        json_obj  = row['json']
        print (json_obj)
        json_res.append(json_obj)
        print(json_res)
    #json = simplejson.dumps(data)

    dict_cur.close()
    data = {'geojson':  mark_safe(json_res)}
    return render(request, 'map.html', data)
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^geojson/$', geojson_provinces, name='geojson_provinces'),
```

models.py

```
class PFT(models.Model):
    species=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # GeoDjango-specific: a geometry field (MultiPolygonField)
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects=models.GeoManager()
    # Returns the string representation of the model.
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.species, self.geom.x, self.geom.y)
```